# Newtonsoft alternative to using JsonConstructorAttribute

Tags: c#, json.net

I have serialized an object to json using newtonsoft json serializer.

Now I want to deserialize it, my object is immutable, it contains two constructors, both with parameters. I have to decorate the second one using the attribute JsonConstructorAttribute.

It works great.

But!

I don't like the idea to decorate my constructor using the attribute, is there an other way to specify it?